# sql select earliest date for multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database that looks like the following;

```
circuit_uid   |  customer_name   | location      | reading_date | reading_time | amps | volts  |  kw  | kwh | kva  |  pf  |  key
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cu1.cb1.r1    | Customer 1       | 12.01.a1      | 2012-01-02   | 00:01:01     | 4.51 | 229.32 | 1.03 |  87 | 1.03 | 0.85 |    15
cu1.cb1.r1    | Customer 1       | 12.01.a1      | 2012-01-02   | 01:01:01     | 4.18 | 230.3 | 0.96 |  90 | 0.96 | 0.84 |    16
cu1.cb1.s2    | Customer 2       | 10.01.a1      | 2012-01-02   | 00:01:01     | 7.34 | 228.14 | 1.67 | 179 | 1.67 | 0.88 | 24009
cu1.cb1.s2    | Customer 2       | 10.01.a1      | 2012-01-02   | 01:01:01     | 9.07 |  228.4 | 2.07 | 182 | 2.07 | 0.85 | 24010
cu1.cb1.r1    | Customer 3       | 01.01.a1      | 2012-01-02   | 00:01:01     | 7.32 | 229.01 | 1.68 | 223 | 1.68 | 0.89 | 48003 
cu1.cb1.r1    | Customer 3       | 01.01.a1      | 2012-01-02   | 01:01:01     | 6.61 | 228.29 | 1.51 | 226 | 1.51 | 0.88 | 48004
```

What I am trying to do is produce a result that has the KWH reading for each customer from the earliest (`min(reading_time)`) on that date, the date will be selected by the user in a web form.

The result would be/should be similar to;

```
Customer 1   87
Customer 2   179
Customer 3   223
```

There are more than the number of rows per day shown here and there are more customers and the number of customers would change regularly.

I do not have much experience with SQL, I have looked at subqueries etc. but I do not have the chops to figure out how arrange it by the earliest reading per customer and then just output the `kwh` column.

This is running in PostgreSQL 8.4 on Redhat/CentOS.

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/939860

Comment: Please ask a **new question**. It's generally not ok to change the nature of the question substantially after good answers have been given. you can always link back to this one for context. I reverted your changes, you can find it in the edit log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select customer_name,
       kwh,
       reading_date, 
       reading_time
from (
   select customer_name,
          kwh,
          reading_time,
          reading_date,
          row_number() over (partition by customer_name order by reading_time) as rn
   from readings
   where reading_date = date '2012-11-17'
) t
where rn = 1
```

As an alternative:

```
select r1.customer_name,
       r1.kwh, 
       r1.reading_date,
       r1.reading_time
from readings r1
where reading_date = date '2012-11-17'
and reading_time = (select min(r2.reading_time)
                    from readings
                    where r2.customer_name = r1.customer_name
                    and r2.read_date = r1.reading_date);
```

But I'd expect the first one to be faster.

Btw: why do you store date and time in two separate columns? Are you aware that this could be handled better with a `timestamp` column?

Comment: Good point about the timestamp column. Extracting date or time is super simple & super fast: `ts_column::date`  or `ts_column::time`.

Comment: i guess it is just my lack of experience that had me split out the date and time. Thank you for your excellent answer. Please accept my apologies and see the revised question.

Answer (score 3):

This should be among the fastest possible solutions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_name)
       customer_name, kwh  -- add more columns as needed.
FROM   readings
WHERE  reading_date = user_date
ORDER  BY customer_name, reading_time
```

Seems to be another application of:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: Erwin thank you for your answer I apologise for changing the question like that. Your answer also returns a perfect result per the question.

Comment: @AlanEnnis: Not a problem. Just ask a new question, you will have more answers in no time. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT rt.circuit_uid ,  rt.customer_name, rt.kwh
   FROM READING_TABLE rt JOIN  
       (SELECT circuit_uid, reading_time
       FROM READING_TABLE
       WHERE reading_date = '2012-01-02'
       GROUP BY customer_uid
       HAVING MIN(reading_time) = reading_time) min_time
   ON (rt.circuit_uid = min_time.circuit_uid 
      AND rt.reading_time = min_time.reading_time);
```

Parameterize the reading_date value in above query.

Comment: That will give you an error because `kwh` is neither in the `group by` clause nor in an aggregate